# error of import tensorflow as tf python 3.6.0

Tags: tensorflow

I downloaded  the tensorflow package for python3.6.0 from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy then installed it by pip, it showed successful . when I import tensorflow as tf,it failed like following

> > > import tensorflow as tf

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. Please post error message as text, not as image.

Answer (score 1):

From [Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources)

> > Install TensorFlow Python dependencies
> >
> > To install TensorFlow, you must install the following packages:
> >
> > - numpy, which is a numerical processing package that TensorFlow requires.
> > - dev, which enables adding extensions to Python.
> > - pip, which enables you to install and manage certain Python packages.
> > - wheel, which enables you to manage Python compressed packages in the wheel (.whl) format.

Install the dependency packages First.

or direct from command prompt.

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

for `CPU` version only for TensorFlow.

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

for `GPU` version of TensorFlow